# Xamarin Android Google Maps Fragment Error

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am trying to use google maps in my xamarin android project. I have installed Google Play Services- Maps, and created an API Key in Google Console.
I used fragment to show map in my activity as shown here in image.[Map Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMqOk.png)

But when I try to instantiate this application, it throws this exception:
"Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment." [MainActivity.cs Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGGyU.png)

Please help me with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Android you are using, you might need to use `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead for the Fragment class type.

Also, have you followed the steps in the [Official Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/) to set up the API keys?